# Use of outdoorsman skill at local map

Tags: wasteland-2, wasteland-2-directors-cut

How can I use the outdoorsman skill at **local map**?

I see it is possible to add it to the hotkeys but every time I use it, I get the Invalid Target popup.

There is no useful documentation explaining how to use it and the only places (at local map) that I can find some utility for that skill is on random checks when getting some plants or saving people on AG Center from the vines.